# Docker + django_extensions + jupyter: OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: django, docker, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I am trying to set up `jupyter` inside a container that contains a Django app. I am using [`django-extensions`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in order to take advantage of the `shell_plus` command. However, when I run it:

```sh
docker-compose exec app python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 125, in run_from_argv
    return super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 62, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 517, in handle
    shell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 253, in run_notebook
    app.initialize(notebook_arguments)
  File "<decorator-gen-117>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1769, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1490, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 174, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. It is needed to pass some [additional notebook arguments](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html#configuration) for `django-extensions` using `NOTEBOOK_KERNEL_SPEC_NAMES`:

```py
NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS = [
    "--ip", "0.0.0.0",
    "--port", "8888",
    "--allow-root"
]
```

You also need to add `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` to your environment variables with value `True`. Otherwise, you will get an error while trying to perform queries using Django ORM.

In addition, make sure to expose the port in the container. In my case, I am using a `docker-compose.yml`, so it will be:

```
ports:
  - 8000:8000
  - 8888:8888 # this is the port at which notebook runs
```

After setting that, running the following command will work like a charm:

```sh
docker-compose exec app python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error using requirements `tornado==5.1.1 and django-extensions==2.2.3`. There is a loop that forces `port 8888` to be bound twice. It fails the second time, because it is bound the first time. I guess, this should go to the django-extensions as a bug. Other requirements. This is on an ubuntu machine using django 2.2.

Comment: Wish, I could upvote my own answer. Found myself saved again today. Something not right with `tornado==5.1.1` Got stuck there because `flower==0.9.3` requires `tornado<6.0` which translates to `5.1.1`.